# Sonata Admin Two-Steps Google Authentication

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, google-authentication, two-step-verification

I followed this guide to setup the two-steps authentication:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/two_step_validation.html

Unfortunately the documentation is very short and I couldn't make it work. These are steps I followed:

1. Configured my `config.yml` like this:

   google_authenticator:
   enabled: true
   server:  my-admin-url.local # Is this my site URL?
2. `php app/console sonata:user:two-step-verification admin` to populate the field?
3. After the login I get this screen. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: A better documentation on Sonata Google Authenticator is available on GitHub at [https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator](https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator). An example in PHP of how to use it can be found at [https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator/blob/2.x/sample/example.php](https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator/blob/2.x/sample/example.php)